# Wordpress Submitted Content

Tags: login, front-end, community

Whats the best approach to build this site in wordpress:

- 2 custom user levels (students, staff).
- staff use standard wordpress backend, students post from frontend.
- one section of the site has content uploaded by users, (title, content, image).
- frontend post creation (preferably custom post type).
- frontend login and password reminder

I've looked at buddypress but it seems too big for what I need. Ideally I want to try and use one plugin for the submission and login, and setup custom post types in functions.php.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/features/form-builder/), a plugin for building custom forms. It includes support for creating posts via frontend user submitted forms. It is well worth the cost. You can also use it to build any other custom forms you may need.

There's [another plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/) that works with Gravity Forms to apply custom post types and pull in custom taxonomies into your user submitted post forms.